# Create one stack with 10 integer elements and then add one element with function

Tags: java, stack

I created a stack with 10 elements:

```
    Stack<Integer> stackA = new Stack<>();
    stackA.push(1);
    stackA.push(2);
    stackA.push(3);
    stackA.push(4);
    stackA.push(5);
    stackA.push(6);
    stackA.push(7);
    stackA.push(8);
    stackA.push(9);
    stackA.push(10);
```

Now, I need to write a method that
using auxiliary stack B adds an element to the bottom of the stack A as an argument.

So if my stack is: `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10` after method `add_on_beggining(0)`
the stack should look `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`

Also, im trying to solve this just with peek, push and pop.

Comment: Can you show us your `add_on_beggining` method, and point where, specifically, are you having any problem(s) while doing this task?

Comment: I dont know how to start, that is my problem :d

Answer (score 0):

you can get the size of stack and pop them in a for loop and save them in an array.
Then push 0(beginning) and the elements of array in-order.

Comment: Yeah, I have in my mind idea how to fix this but my problem is how to write code that will work

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is a homework assignment, and you are forced to use a self-implemented class, use `LinkedList`. It implements `Deque`, which is both a stack and a queue.
With it, you can add elements on both ends, while using the methods provided by the stack (push, pop, peek...).

Deque: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html

Answer (score 0):

example implementation:

```
import java.util.Stack;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomStack<Integer> stackA = new CustomStack<>();
        stackA.push(1);
        stackA.push(2);
        stackA.push(3);
        stackA.push(4);
        stackA.push(5);
        stackA.push(6);
        stackA.push(7);
        stackA.push(8);
        stackA.push(9);
        stackA.push(10);

        Stack<Integer> stackB = stackA.addOnBeginning(0);
        System.out.println(stackB);
    }
}


class CustomStack<E> extends Stack<E> {
    CustomStack addOnBeginning(E value) {
        CustomStack<E> stack = new CustomStack<>();
        stack.push(value);
        stack.addAll(this);
        return stack;
    }
}
```

output:
`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`

You may want to change class/variable names. Note that you don't have to return CustomStack from addOnBeginning as well as create `new CustomStack<>();`.

Or just use Deque as mentioned above.

Comment: Cannot find symbol: `addOnBeginning`

Comment: Can't really answer without your code, but make sure you're using this method on CustomStack instance

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

import java.util.List;

import java.util.Stack;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Stack<Integer> stackA = new Stack<>();

    stackA.push(1);
    stackA.push(2);
    stackA.push(3);
    stackA.push(4);
    stackA.push(5);
    stackA.push(6);
    stackA.push(7);
    stackA.push(8);
    stackA.push(9);
    stackA.push(10);

    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();

    int elementToAdd = 100;

    //Add first
    temp.add(elementToAdd);

    for (Integer el : stackA) {
        temp.add(el);
    }

    stackA.clear();

    stackA.addAll(temp);

    System.out.println(stackA);


}
```

}

Comment: That works fine, but no on way that I want, but thank you